# The assembly of "GCC -S" output: why does .globl locate ahead of .data?

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler

```
    .file   "test.c"
    .globl  a1
    .data
    .align 4
    .type   a1, @object
    .size   a1, 4
a1:
    .long   111
    .globl  a2
    .align 4
    .type   a2, @object
    .size   a2, 8
a2:
    .long   1
    .long   2
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    ...
    ...
```

From the context, I think it should be:

```
    .data
    .globl  a1
```

Why does GCC put .data behind .globl ?

Answer (score 4):

> Why does GCC put .data behind .globl ?

It doesn't matter. The `.globl` directive only tells the assembler that the symbol should be global (visible to the linker). What matters is that the label itself (i.e. the line `a1:`) is placed after `.data`.

Comment: Don't you think put .data ahead of .globl is more consistent. For: .data --> .globl a1 --> .globl a2

Comment: Yeah it might be. But it has no effect on the output.